# Cannot link image to url (<img> tag inside of <a> tag not working for slideshow)

Tags: html, slideshow

I have a slideshow and I want to link each slide to some url, which should be easy, but it's not working.

I'm using the slider from here: http://dev7studios.com/lean-slider/
If you don't want to download the code, I guess you can just use inspect element and edit it to test it yourself.

```
            ...
                <div class="slide1 lean-slider-slide">
                    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                </div>
            ...
```

I also tried using onclick with javascript with no luck.

```
<script>
function test(){
    document.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
}
</script>

<img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" onclick="test()" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I uploaded the default demo version to my [website](http://andyweb.info/phpmvc/Lean-Slider/demo/index.php), linking all images to google.com. I have not made any changes to the original code other than adding the links. I assume that you've already tried that but I cannot see what the issue could be. Usually problems like these have to do with paths to scripts and stylesheets but these seem pretty straightforward. At least there's a working example to go by. The code I'm using is below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Lean Slider Demo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="scripts/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../lean-slider.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lean-slider.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sample-styles.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <div id="slider">
            <div class="slide1">
                <a href="http://google.com" target="blank"></><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide2">
                <a href="http://google.com" target="blank"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide3">
                <a href="http://google.com" target="blank"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide4">
                <a href="http://google.com" target="blank"><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="slider-direction-nav"></div>
        <div id="slider-control-nav"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var slider = $('#slider').leanSlider({
            directionNav: '#slider-direction-nav',
            controlNav: '#slider-control-nav'
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! One strange thing I noticed is that it only links it when all four slides have the modified href line.  But at least its working now, so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Its not working correctly.
Expected is each image can have their own hyperlinks, but with lean-slider, only last hyperlink is applicable with all images.
In you case you have given google.com with each image so it seems it is working fine, but once you change each URL then you will notice that it is not going to last hyperlink.

Thanks,
Krishan

Answer (score 0):

but the solution i cant have diferent URL´s, always take the last link; play with the css you can force the position of elements and enable yhe link for each image:

```
/*lean slider overwrite*/
#slider-control-nav, #slider-direction-nav
{
 z-index:3;
}

.lean-slider-slide.current
{
 z-index:2;
}

.lean-slider-slide.current a
{
 float:left;
}
```